# From xlsx-file to Entity Relation Diagram

Tags: excel, graph, entity, xlsx, relation

I would like to convert a relational database encoded in an xlsx-file into an image of a directed graph that shows the entities, some of the attributes and the directed relations.

The xlsx-file is organized is follows. Column A contains entity names and Column B the corresponding attribute names. Column C contains entity names as well, encoding the relation from one entity (in Column A) to another (in Column B). Column A may contain duplicate names. Column B may contain Null entries. An exmplary file can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gpcqzyls3mqulhz/database.xlsx?dl=0. The outcome of this particular file should be something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPIjs.png).

The original xlsx-file is much larger. By using yED and small workarounds I made my life already easier. But continuing this way would take 3 days I reckon. I have programming experience in Java and Python, but I can't really estimate the effort of such a solution and the choice of an appropriate library is difficult.

Regards from Frankfurt,

Johannes

Comment: On a bigger scale, I'm looking for something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/abfXT.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be found here: The solutions can be found here: http://yed.yworks.com/support/qa/9808/relational-entities-in-excel-file-to-directed-graph